# Excel VBA ChangeFileAccess stops macro execution

Tags: excel, vba

```
    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite
    End If
```

My macro finishes execution after changing mode of workbook to ReadWrite (Debugger won't go any further). How do I solve this problem?

I have no idea what to try. Probably changing worbook read mode to edit reopens the Workbook resulting in break of the macro. But I have no idea how to execute the rest of the code after. The only thing that comes to my mind is to create a txt file with a variable and then execute the rest of the code in WorkbookOpen() based on the variable.

EDIT: After further investigation WorkbookOpen() does not execute after changing AccessMode. Now I am clueless.
This is from microsoft REMARKS:
"If you have a file open in read-only mode, you don't have exclusive access to the file. If you change a file from read-only to read/write, Microsoft Excel must load a new copy of the file to ensure that no changes were made while you had the file open as read-only."

Any ideas how can I execute the rest of macro after I change the accessmode?

Reproduction steps:

1. Create a Workbook that opens always in ReadOnly mode. WorkbookOpen() has ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
2. Create 2 buttons: 1 for log in, 2 for log out
3. LogIn has ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite AND messageBox after
4. LogOut has ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly AND messageBox after

What I want:
I want multiple users to work on the file at the same time.
Sometimes only selected users are required to make some changes to the file, so I came up with log-in system.
The problem is I am unable to make a macro that sets workbook to edit mode, makes some changes and then saves it and reenters read only mode.

Comment: I have tested the code with Excel 365 w/o any issure. The code execution wasn't terminated.

Comment: But, when you try  setting `ReadWrite` attribute don't you see a warning message telling that it is 'locked for editing`?

Comment: Can you explain **why do you need such an approach**? What do you try accomplishing  changing such an attribute when the workbook is already open?

Comment: I don't want a popup message asking if a file should be really opened in read only mode,  I want this file to be in edit mode only in certain cases for a brief moment (because it will be used by multiple users over network) or after a specific user logs in with his own password (to register changes in a log file).

Comment: So, what you try doing is not possible! If somebody else already open that file, how do you imagine that, **even if Windows/Excel will let you make the workbook read/write**, what will happen with the others working on the same (readOnly) file? The single solution I can imagine, but also possible to create trouble, for such a case is: 1. Save the modified workbook with a different name in a specific folder, with the existing name plus its user name. 2 Somebody else or the same user can overwrite the existing file with the new one, than change the file name as the original one.

Comment: But what about the other users making modifications in the same time? Who will be able to keep track of all of them and what to choose if more than one modify the same range?